# No nginx cash if utm_campaign present

Tags: nginx

I want to cache pages on nginx for guests. But if ?utm_campaign is present in url I need to pass that requet to apache.

How can I exclude from caching those requests, that have utm_campaign key in URI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean exclude from the proxy cache ? Assuming your utm argument is given a value when present, you can use `proxy_no_cache` directive :

```
location /foo {
    proxy_pass http://apache:port/;
    proxy_cache mycache;
    proxy_no_cache $arg_utm_campaign;
}
```